Что это такое и как это отключить?

Здраствуйте, не знаю как называется этот блок, он мне сильно мешает, кто-нибудь знает как это отключить?

Sticky Scroll, только непонятно при чём тут браузер

Включить/выключить

В visual studio code нажмите F1
В строке введите sticky
Выберите опцию View: Toogle Editor Sticky Scroll


Спасибо!!!!!! <3

можете отметить как правильный ответ
